# Unity: Rotation of an Object is not working correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I am trying to rotate the light source of my Scene on one Axis with this code:

```
IEnumerator SunMoving()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Quaternion fromAngle = transform.rotation;
        Quaternion toAngle = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + (Vector3.left * dayRotation));

        for(float t = 0f;  t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromAngle, toAngle, t);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}

void Start()
{
    dayRotation = 360 / daySeconds;
    //nightRotation = 180 / nightSeconds;
    StartCoroutine(SunMoving());
}
```

But it is not working correctly.
I am really new to quaternions and rotation in general, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: `But it is not working correctly.` what exactly does this mean?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, the object beeing rotated would sometimes just stop at a point an get stuck there rotating back and forth. I actually just could not figure out, how this outcome would be possilbe. I will have to further look into quaternions and rotation to understand :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to animate a sun object (directional light) you don't lerp between two different rotations but calculate angles from a formula that approximates this continuous motion

[image: sun light controller]

```
// src* https://gist.github.com/andrew-raphael-lukasik/2f337c0e6c467f084cded9bf63dd8556
using UnityEngine;

public class SunController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField][Range(0,1)] float _dayTime = 0.5f;// 0.5 means noon
    [SerializeField] float _timeScale = 1;
    [SerializeField] Light _sun = null;// make sure it is directional
    [SerializeField] Vector2 _sunAtMidnight = new Vector2(45,0);// degrees
    [SerializeField] Vector2 _earthRotationAxis = new Vector2(-45,0);// degrees, axis relative to your location (so pointing straight up if you are on a N or S pole)
    const float degreesPerSecond = 360f / secondsPerDay;
    const float secondsPerDay = 24*60*60;// seconds per day
    [SerializeField] AnimationCurve _sunIntensity = new AnimationCurve(
        new Keyframe(0,0) ,
        new Keyframe(0.25f,0) ,
        new Keyframe(0.5f,1) ,
        new Keyframe(0.75f,0) ,
        new Keyframe(1,0)
    );
    [SerializeField] Gradient _sunColor = new Gradient{ colorKeys=new GradientColorKey[]{
        new GradientColorKey(new Color(1,0.3f,0,1),0) ,
        new GradientColorKey(Color.white,0.5f) ,
        new GradientColorKey(new Color(1,0.3f,0,1),1)
    } };

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // step simulation time:
        _dayTime = ( _dayTime + ( Time.fixedDeltaTime * _timeScale ) / secondsPerDay ) % 1f;

        // update directional light:
        Vector3 sunPositionNow = SunPositionAtTime(_dayTime);
        _sun.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation( -sunPositionNow );
        _sun.intensity = _sunIntensity.Evaluate(_dayTime);
        _sun.color = _sunColor.Evaluate(_dayTime);
        _sun.enabled = _sun.intensity>0;
    }

    /// <param name="t">0-1 value range</param>
    Vector3 SunPositionAtTime ( float t )
    {
        Vector3 midnightDir = Quaternion.Euler((Vector3)_sunAtMidnight) * Vector3.forward;
        Vector3 earthAxisDir = Quaternion.Euler((Vector3)_earthRotationAxis) * Vector3.forward;
        return Quaternion.AngleAxis( t*secondsPerDay*degreesPerSecond , earthAxisDir ) * midnightDir;
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    void OnDrawGizmos ()
    {
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        
        Gizmos.color = Color.cyan * 0.3f;
        Gizmos.DrawRay( position , Quaternion.Euler((Vector3)_earthRotationAxis) * Vector3.forward );
        
        Gizmos.color = Color.black;
        Gizmos.DrawRay( position , Quaternion.Euler((Vector3)_sunAtMidnight) * Vector3.forward );

        if( Application.isPlaying )
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.white;
            Gizmos.DrawRay( position , SunPositionAtTime(_dayTime) );
        }

        int numSteps = 100;
        for( int i=0 ; i<=numSteps ; i++ )
        {
            float t = (float)i / (float)numSteps;
            Gizmos.color = _sunColor.Evaluate(t) * new Color(1,1,1,Mathf.Max(_sunIntensity.Evaluate(t),0.05f));
            Gizmos.DrawRay( position , SunPositionAtTime(t) );
        }

        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow * 0.3f;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere( position , 1f );
        
        int dayTimeSeconds = (int)(_dayTime * secondsPerDay);
        int h = dayTimeSeconds/(60*60);
        int m = (dayTimeSeconds%(60*60))/60;
        int s = dayTimeSeconds%60;
        UnityEditor.Handles.color = Color.red;
        UnityEditor.Handles.Label( position , $"time of day: {h:00.}:{m:00.}:{s:00.}" );
    }
#endif

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In general do not use [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html) unless you know how they work:

> When using the `.eulerAngles` property to set a rotation, it is important to understand that although you are providing X, Y, and Z rotation values to describe your rotation, those values are not stored in the rotation. Instead, the X, Y & Z values are converted to the Quaternion's internal format.
>
> When you read the `.eulerAngles` property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is **more than one way** to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be **quite different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation**. See bottom scripting example for more information.
>
> To avoid these kinds of problems, the recommended way to work with rotations is to avoid relying on consistent results when reading .eulerAngles particularly when attempting to gradually increment a rotation to produce animation. For better ways to achieve this, see the Quaternion * operator.

rather calculate your target rotation as

```
Quaternion fromAngle = transform.rotation;
Quaternion toAngle = fromAngle * Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.left * dayRotation);
```

---

Further using `Lerp` in your use case of an endless continuous linear rotation seems a bit unnecessary.

You could without dealing with the Quaternions at all also simply [`Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) by a fix angle:

```
[SerializeFied]
private float daySeconds = 1f;

private void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(-360f / daySeconds * Time.deltTime, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the update function instead of the start function to rotate stuff.
Secondly quaternions have an extra dimension w which needs to be computed. A difficult aspect of quaternions is that the order of operation matters a lot.
->  transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromAngle, toAngle, t); not sure about this line.

Comment: Hi Andrei, please allow me to clear few things out ok?

**"You should use the update function instead of the start function to rotate stuff"**
He is using `Update` but indirectly via a `Coroutine`

**"Secondly quaternions have an extra dimension w which needs to be computed"**
`Quaternion.Euler` is a handy method that computes all these quaternion components for you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).